# Помогите написать правильно criteria в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Не могу понять как сделать сравнение в hibernate cruteria. Есть такой метод

```
@Override
    public List<PollEvent> getPollForUpdate(IncomingSms incommingSMS) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PollEvent.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", 0));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("call.callingnum", incommingSMS.getSourceAddress()));
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

Он должен вернуть список объектов. Но ворачивает ошибку. ругается на `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("call.callingnum", incommingSMS.getSourceAddress()));`

В классе `PollEvent` есть поле `call` вот оно

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CALL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Calls call;
```

а у него есть поле `callingnum` по которому  яи хочу сравнить

```
@Column(name = "CALLINGNUM", length = 15)
    private String callingnum;
```

Ошибка которую я получаю

```
could not resolve property: call.callingnum of: polls.entety.PollEvent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом случае необходимо создать либо вложенный `criteria`:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PollEvent.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", 0));
criteria.createCriteria("call")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("callingnum", incommingSMS.getSourceAddress()));
```

либо использовать `alias`:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PollEvent.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", 0));
criteria.createAlias("call", "c");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.callingnum", incommingSMS.getSourceAddress()));
```

[Документация](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations)

Comment: Нашел решение раньше но ответ правильный. спасибо!